# InputStreamReader.read() how does it 'not' read already read buffers?

Tags: java, android

I was using the code below and was just wondering why whenever the while loop is repeated, inputBuffer reads from the end of what had been last read.

What's stopping it from reading the same 500 characters all the time as the loop goes around? Is it just how InputStreamReader is constructed?

So what I got from Java site is below.

Reads characters into an array. This method will block until some input is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.

It does say it reads until the end is reached but what's stopping it from assuming that the end has already been reached because the character buffer size is smaller than the whole InputStream when it goes around the first while loop?

I have a little bit more code related to this but I think you guys can sufficiently understand how it goes.

```
StringBuilder tempBuffer = new StringBuilder();

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
int charRead;
char[] inputBuffer = new char[500];

while (true){
    charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer);
    if (charRead <=0){
    break;
    }
    tempBuffer.append(String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead));
}

return tempBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: It maintains its current position, hence next read will not read from the start but from where it was.

Comment: so that's within the functionality of InputStreamReader itself? so when its is read to a buffer it will 'always' remember to maintain its last read position? @HyperZ

Comment: I do not know exactly how it is implemented, i would have to take a look at it. But i presume InputStreamReader maintains a current.

Comment: Okay well thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputStreamReader` is just a wrapper around an `InputStream`.

Any `InputStream` is just a wrapper around some file or socket or other resource provided by the operating system.

The operating system knows where you've read to and delivers data to the next read operation starting from that position, and increments the position accordingly. Or, in the case of a socket for example, it has already thrown away the data you've already read.

It doesn't have anything to do with the `Reader` or the `InputStream`.

An obvious exception to this is `ByteArrayInputStream`, which provides its own position.

Comment: Oh wow so OS itself remembers the position? Thats actually pretty cool

Comment: So when you say obvious exception you mean 'ByteArrayInputStream' has its own method of keeping record of where the data was read upto instead of OS having to deal with it right?